# Adding legends and info to datavisualization tkiz

Tags: charts, tkz-graph

I would like to add some information to this graph and I am failing. More specifically,

- I want the X axis to have the label "nodes" and the Y axis to be seconds
- I also want the first data set to be called "static" and the second data set to be called "dynamic", perhaps using a red and blue color.

I had to make the graph very vertical to make the "linear" data more visible. I appreciate any help or feedback.

Thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization} %for graphs and pictures
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions} %for graphs and pictures

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [scientific axes,
                          x axis={attribute=nodes, length=10cm},
                          y axis={attribute=seconds, length=20cm},
                          visualize as line]
  data {
    nodes, seconds
    3,0.009
    30,0.003
    111,0.005
    354,0.019
    1083,0.097
    3270,0.044
    9831,0.064
    29514,0.501
    88563,2.276
    265710,7.439
    797151,27.578
    2391474,128.611
  }
  data {
    nodes, seconds
    3,0.091
    30,0.495
    111,2.789
    354,3.390
    1083,5.021
    3270,20.149
    9831,48.015
    29514,158.442
    88563,857.381
    265710,2693.862
    797151,8771.571
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pgfplots`? I think that it's much easier with it...

Comment: @Rmano please see me previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686423/drawing-a-bar-chat-horizontal-or-log-line-chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization} %for graphs and pictures
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions} %for graphs and pictures

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [
  scientific axes,
  x axis={attribute=nodes, length=10cm, label=nodes},
  y axis={attribute=seconds, length=20cm, label=seconds},
  visualize as line/.list={foo, bar},
  foo={style=red,label in legend={text=Foo}},
  bar={style=blue,label in legend={text=Bar}},
]
  data[set=foo] {
    nodes, seconds
    3,0.009
    30,0.003
    111,0.005
    354,0.019
    1083,0.097
    3270,0.044
    9831,0.064
    29514,0.501
    88563,2.276
    265710,7.439
    797151,27.578
    2391474,128.611
  }
  data[set=bar] {
    nodes, seconds
    3,0.091
    30,0.495
    111,2.789
    354,3.390
    1083,5.021
    3270,20.149
    9831,48.015
    29514,158.442
    88563,857.381
    265710,2693.862
    797151,8771.571
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]