# re-creating pgfplots example with different data where a column has a format of 2^x

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to re-create [this pgfplots graph with different data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686587/122628). Instead of "Depth" I have "non-terminal count" or `nts` for short in the table and I want that a-axis value to be 2^x number format instead of x (its currently x). The "nodes" column is still there.

This is my attempt

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}% for starburst
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

% JastAdd crashed at size 2^13
\pgfplotstableread{
nts  Nodes    ApsTime       ApsMemory        JastAddTime        JastAddMemory
8      17045        0.6    78     0.8     63
9      67244       2.3    137     2.8     126
10      265762      9.3    479     15     388
11      1024167      72    1288     127     2793
12      3596625     246    5052    983     11073
13      9075268     861    14362    nan       nan
}\followdata


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    slanted blocks/.style={
        draw, fill=white, font=\tiny\ttfamily, rotate=45,
        anchor=south west, inner sep=2pt
    }]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis line style = {thick, gray},
        ymode = log,
        ymin = .2,
        xtick = {8,9,...,13},
        xlabel = {Non-terminal count},
        ylabel = {Time (seconds)},
        legend style = {nodes={right, font=\scriptsize},
            at={(0.05,0.9)}, anchor=west},
        clip mode = individual,
        grid = major,
        label style={font=\tiny},
        tick label style={font=\tiny}
        ]
        \addplot table[x=nts, y=JastAddTime]{\followdata};
        \addplot table[x=nts, y=ApsTime]{\followdata};
        \legend{JastAdd, APS}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{8,9,...,12}{
            \node[slanted blocks] at ({#1+1},.2)
                {\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Nodes}\of{\followdata}\pgfplotsretval};
        }
        \node[slanted blocks] at (7.1,.2) {\# of nodes};
        \node[starburst, fill=yellow, draw=red, thick, font=\tiny\ttfamily,
            inner sep=0pt, starburst point height=6pt]
            at (12.5, 2000) {crash!};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should really try to minimize your examples in questions. You are correctly posting compilable examples, but they are far from *minimum*...  my experience is that I often find the problem myself in the "try to reduce this to the minimum"  exercise. For example, in this question: reduce it to two-three points, one graph, just the minimum set of packages needed.

Comment: @Rmano I updated my attempt

Comment: It does not compile for me... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood correctly. Are you looking for `xticklabel` options? You can find it in page 343 of the (current) `pgfplots` manual.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}% for starburst
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

% JastAdd crashed at size 2^13
\pgfplotstableread{
nts  Nodes    ApsTime       ApsMemory        JastAddTime        JastAddMemory
8      17045        0.6    78     0.8     63
9      67244       2.3    137     2.8     126
10      265762      9.3    479     15     388
11      1024167      72    1288     127     2793
12      3596625     246    5052    983     11073
13      9075268     861    14362    nan       nan
}\followdata

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    slanted blocks/.style={
        draw, fill=white, font=\tiny\ttfamily, rotate=45,
        anchor=south west, inner sep=2pt
    }]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis line style = {thick, gray},
        ymode = log,
        ymin = .2,
        xtick = {8,9,...,13},
        xlabel = {Non-terminal count},
        ylabel = {Time (seconds)},
        legend style = {nodes={right, font=\scriptsize},
            at={(0.05,0.9)}, anchor=west},
        clip mode = individual,
        grid = major,
        label style={font=\tiny},
        tick label style={font=\tiny},
        %%% Added: how to create the ticks, manual page 343 "Tick Options"
        xticklabel={$2^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
        ]
        \addplot table[x=nts, y=JastAddTime]{\followdata};
        \addplot table[x=nts, y=ApsTime]{\followdata};
        \legend{JastAdd, APS}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,...,5}{%%% changed to compile
            \node[slanted blocks] at ({#1+8},.2) %% changed to adjust shift
                {\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Nodes}\of{\followdata}\pgfplotsretval};
        }
        \node[slanted blocks] at (7.1,.2) {\# of nodes};
        \node[starburst, fill=yellow, draw=red, thick, font=\tiny\ttfamily,
            inner sep=0pt, starburst point height=6pt]
            at (12.5, 2000) {crash!};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]